# Why does multisite bypass WordPress for wp-content, wp-admin, wp-includes and .php files?

Tags: redirect, htaccess, mod-rewrite

When you set up WordPress to use multisite, you're directed to modify your `.htaccess` file to use one of the following, which are outlined in the admin and the [WordPress documentation](https://wordpress.org/support/article/htaccess/#multisite):

**Subfolder**

```
...
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
...
```

**Subdomain**

```
...
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
...
```

I understand what those rules do. Instead of sending the requests through to WordPress to handle, `.htaccess` sends the user directly to the directory or file, whether it exists or not.

What I can't figure out is why. Why is this necessary for multisite, but not for single site installs?

I ask because we're trying to use the [Redirection](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/) plugin to create redirects for some files in `wp-content/uploads` and some files that end in `.php`. Unfortunately, because those requests don't make it to WordPress, the redirects are never triggered. We don't want to modify the `.htaccess` rules without first understanding their purpose. And that has been a challenge.

Comment: For single site, the file _/wp-admin/edit.php_ exists just like this on the filesystem. For multisite, _/foo/wp-admin/edit.php_ does not exist like this on the filesystem.

Comment: Thanks @kero, that makes sense for the subfolders and makes the redirects there more clear, but what about the subdomain redirects?

Comment: I haven't worked with MultiSite in some time. Isn't it the case that WP creates subfolders inside wp-content to distinguish between subsites (even if you have subdomain)? So if you access `foo.example.com/wp-content/uploads/bar.jpg` it needs to rewrite, because the file is actually under `/var/www/html/wp-content/blogs.dir/3/uploads/bar.jpg`

Comment: Thanks @kero. There may have been a need to redirect those at some point, but that isn't the case now. Site ID #1 has its files stored directly within `/wp-content/uploads/`, while the other sites are within folders in `/wp-content/uploads/sites/`. All that said, the rewrite rule actually avoids redirecting them at all by bypassing WordPress and going straight to the provided URL.